# SQL Server - Find last row that matches a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and I'm having trouble creating a query to find the last entry in a table where one column contains part of a specific string. I have a database similar to:

```
Part Number | Description | Qty 
------------+-------------+-----
   MO1      | Big Motor   | 1 
   MO2      | Small Motor | 5   
   XYZ      | Garbage     | 1 
   BO1      | Big Bolt    | 1 
   BO2      | Small Bolt  | 2
```

I'm looking for a way to query any entry in which the "Part Number" starts with "MO" then return just the last entry ("MO2/Small Motor/5" in this case). The part numbers are always sequential, but there can be a lot of junk data in between clumps of properly formatted numbers. I'm much more used to working with Excel where I can "Find" a string by searching in reverse order, but I don't know how to do the equivalent in SQL.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "last entry" in a table, unless a column explicitly specifies the ordering.

Comment: What do you mean by `junk of data in between`?  Not just MO1, MO2 -- maybe MOjunkdata1, but always ending in numeric characters?

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I imagine the ordering is by the last numeric characters in `partnumber`...

Comment: Which is the primary key-foreign key in the table ? On what column you need ordering to get the last row from the table ?

Comment: @sgeddes Junk data meaning part numbers which do not follow the "XXYY" pattern where XX is string characters and YY are numeric characters. Yes, the ordering is by last numeric character.

Answer (score 3):

If by "last" you mean the largest value starting with `MO`, then you can do:

```
select top 1 t.*
from t
where partnumber like 'MO%'
order by partnumber desc     -- or some other column that specifies the ordering
```

If the numbers could end up looking like MO101, then you can do:

```
order by len(partnumber) desc, partnumber desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you could have `junk data` in between `MO` and the numeric part number, then here's one option to `order by` the ending characters:

```
select top 1 *
from yourtable
where partnumber like 'mo%'
order by cast(right(partnumber, patindex('%[^0-9 ]%',reverse(partnumber)) - 1) as int) desc
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2e6a/1)

Using `reverse` with `patindex` you can get the remaining numeric characters at the end of the string.  Then `right` makes it easy with `cast` to order the results.

Comment: I believe I may have stated the wrong thing, this SQL code is being used through MS Access, so it's not SQL server? I ask because I was getting a syntax error with this code. Through some digging, I assumed it was because "Patindex()" needed to be changed to "InStr()" and "Reverse()" changed to "Strreverse()". With those changes the code runs but doesn't select anything. I think it's due to a Access not having the "%" and "^" operator functionality? Is there a replacement for that in Access?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 *
FROM
    {TableName}
WHERE
    [Part Number] LIKE '%MO%'
ORDER BY
    [Part Number] DESC
```

> The part numbers are always sequential

Reverse the order by part number and select the first one

If you want 'Mo' to be a variable change to

```
DECLARE
    @PartSearch NVARCHAR(MAX) = **'Mo'**
SELECT
    TOP 1 *
FROM
    {TableName}
WHERE
    [Part Number] LIKE '%' + @PartSearch + '%'
ORDER BY
    [Part Number] DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9385d/3